# How to rollback collect() statements with Snowpark and Python

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to execute a series of sql statements only if they are all successful. The sample code below explains my idea. Begin a transaction, execute some sql statements, if they work commit them, if one one fails, rollback. I can't find documentation or examples that would support this idea. It does work with the snowflake connector but not Snowpark... Any insights?

```
with builder_object.create() as session:
 
    try:
        session.sql('BEGIN').collect()
    
        ## If the Two statements below run, commit them, otherwise rollback ### 
        session.sql("A working sql stament...").collect()
 
        session.sql('A Failing sql statement...').collect()
 
        session.sql('COMMIT').collect()
 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        session.sql('ROLLBACK').collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a custom class that will have a context manager behave as in the desired way https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/snowpark-extensions-py/tree/main/extras/context_helper

Note for DDL statements snowflake automatically commits them so there is no rolling back. But you can rollback DML statements.